# Changing legend format for float numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib, windrose

The following sample code from [Windrose](https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) ax plot creates a legend which I want to control the number of decimal and fraction digits considering that data are shown in float.

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the labels only, and leave alone the intervals, or do you want to change the intervals and have Windrose format the resulting numbers, or eventually you want to change the formatting and the intervals at once. I understand that you did know what you want when you wrote your question, but most of us don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the bins, they can be explicitly set (either a number of bins between min and max value, or a list of bin edges). The default are 6 bins. See [the Windrose bar docs](https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bar#windrose.WindroseAxes.bar). Note that the default bins aren't rounded to 1 decimal, the code just only displays 1 decimal.

There is a [parameter](https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bar#windrose.WindroseAxes.legend) to control the number of digits in the legend, e.g. `ax.set_legend(decimal_places=2)`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import numpy as np

# Create wind speed and direction variables
ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend(decimal_places=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: windrose with decimal places in legend]